# Rotate Image 5 degrees each time user clicks button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, cgaffinetransform

I am creating a custom image editor for a project where I am stuck at rotating images by 5 degrees forward and backward.
here is what I have tried so far

```
 1. self.cropImageView.transform =
    self.cropImageView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double(5) *
    .pi/180)) 
 2. self.cropImageView.transform =
    CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double(5) * .pi/180) )
```

Here is the issue in 1 case image only rotates one time and in another case, the image rotates but the image size is getting smaller as I rotate it.

[image]

Comment: don't you mean `Rotate Image 5 degrees each time user clicks button in swift`?

Comment: You have to memorise the current rotation or apply rotation to the transform of the image view . In your case you rotate the image with an absolute angle so it will be either -5 or +5 degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will only rotate the imageView,if the image size changes,you may have missed some code.

```
func rotate(isForward: Bool) {
    self.cropImageView.transform = self.cropImageView.transform.rotated(by: (isForward ? -1 : 1)  * .pi * (5.0 / 180.0))
}
```